# Cypress test code executes BEFORE the before() hook finishes

Tags: authentication, testing, e2e-testing, cypress

Apologies for the likelihood that this is a possibly stupid question, but i can't for the life of me find an answer. My understanding (and current use of such hooks in other e2e frameworks) is that a before() or beforeEach() hook should COMPLETE before the test code runs... correct? I mean, otherwise, what is the point? But my tests start executing before the before() hook finishes, so then the test fails, as the before() is waiting on auth data in order to be logged in and visit the protected URL... Why aren't the tests waiting for the before() and the beforeEach() to finish? An aside: I am not logging in via the UI, but with cy.request as our app uses Auth0 (this has been a headache with cypress in itself)--could this be the problem? That there's nothing it's waiting for in the DOM?) I'm hoping to move from selenium/nightwatch to cypress, but the issues i'm having with the auth process is making it challenging... any insight would be greatly appreciated!! :)

here's the code that's ailing me: (and the tests DO pass when the login happens IN the test, but i need it to execute in the before! additionally, moving the before hooks to the support/index.js also does nothing to remedy this.) -->

```
describe('Header modules test', () => {

    before(function () {
        console.log('testing 123 why does the test not wait for me to finish?')

        cy.loginWithCyRequest()
            .then(resp => {
                return resp.body.access_token
            }).as('token')
    })

    beforeEach(function () {
        cy.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
            win.localStorage.setItem('access_token', this.token)
        })
    })


    it('checks header modules on the left', function () {
        cy.visit('https://qa.ware2goproject.com/merchant')
            .get('[data-test="merchant_dashboard_title"]').should('have.text', 'Dashboard')
        headerModules.checkModulesLength()
        headerModules.checkModulesMatch()
    })

    it('checks header modules on the right', function () {
        cy.visit('https://qa.ware2goproject.com/merchant')
        headerModules.checkRightNav()
        headerModules.checkAccountDropdown()
    })

})
```

Comment: I tried to run  your code (without the `loginWithCyRequest` and `headerModules` commands. The call order was fine. Can you try adding some `cy.pause()` / `cy.log()` to verify your login works correctly or to show how the async calls in the before hooks mix with actual tests?

Comment: For testing purposes you can add `cy.get("@token").visit(...)` to  your code. Were you able to solve the problems?